# Suma de dos arreglos en uno

Tags: java

Necesito que me ayuden a colocar estos dos arreglos en un solo arreglo:

```
    //Zona codigo 
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese tamaño del arreglo A");
    n = in.nextInt();
    v = new int [n]; //valor asignado
    System.out.println("\nIngrese tamaño del arreglo B");
    n2 = in.nextInt();
    v2 = new int [n2]; //valor asignado

     //Lleno arreglo A
     System.out.println("\nArreglo A: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1); 
        System.out.print(v[i] + " - "); //arreglo original}
      } 
    System.out.println("\nEl arreglo A, ordenado, es5: ");          
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                          
        for( int j = i ; j < n ; j++){                          
            if ( v[j]< v[i] ) {                             
                aux = v[j];                                     
                v[j]= v[i];                                     
                v[i]= aux;
            } 
        } System.out.print(v[i] + " - "); 
    }
     //Lleno arreglo B
     System.out.println("\nArreglo B: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        v2[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1); 
        System.out.print(v2[i] + " - "); //arreglo original}

      } 
    System.out.println("\nEl arreglo B, ordenado, es: ");          
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {                          
        for( int j = i ; j < n2 ; j++){                          
            if ( v2[j]< v2[i] ) {                             
                 aux = v2[j];                                     
                v2[j]= v2[i];                                     
                v2[i]= aux;
            } 
        }  
        System.out.print(v2[i] + " - ");
    }
```

Comment: Lo de "sumar"... ¿te refieres a concatenar una matriz tras otra? ¿o a sumar sus elementos entre sí?

Comment: Disculpa que insista de nuevo. Con "acomodar" ¿te refieres a concatenar? ¿poner en primer lugar los elementos de una matriz y tras ellos los elementos de la otra? ¿De manera que aparezcan ordenados en la matriz resultante o manteniendo el orden que tenían en la matriz de origen? ¿Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/362560/edit) y poner un ejemplo con dos o tres elementos en cada matriz?

Answer (score 1):

He preparado un repositorio github con el código propuesto y explicado en esta respuesta:

- Repositorio github: https://github.com/ojgarciab/362560-stackoverflow-es
- Probar en línea: https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/362560-stackoverflow-es

---

Hay varias formas de realizar el trabajo, aunque quizá la más sencilla es definir una nueva matriz (que llamaré `v3`) que tenga el tamaño de `v` más el de `v2`:

```
/* Dos formas de crear la matriz, usa la que prefieras: */
int[] v3 = new int[v.length + v2.length];
int[] v3 = new int[n + n2];
```

Luego puedes agregar también ese mismo valor en `v3` cuando generas `v`:

```
System.out.println("\nArreglo A: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    v[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1);
    System.out.print(v[i] + " - "); //arreglo original
    /* Agregamos a la matriz final el elemento */
    v3[indice++] = v[i];
}
```

Y lo mismo cuando generas `v2`:

```
System.out.println("\nArreglo B: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
    v2[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1); 
    System.out.print(v2[i] + " - "); //arreglo original
    /* Agregamos a la matriz final el elemento */
    v3[indice++] = v2[i];
}
```

Al final de tu programa, tendrás en `v3` los valores generados en `v` y `v2`, que podrás ordenar como hiciste con el resto (estás usando un algoritmo que se llama "burbuja"):

```
System.out.println("\nEl arreglo completo, ordenado, es: ");          
for (int i = 0; i < v3.length; i++) {                          
    for( int j = i ; j < v3.length ; j++){                          
        if ( v3[j]< v3[i] ) {                             
            aux = v3[j];                                     
            v3[j]= v3[i];                                     
            v3[i]= aux;
        } 
    }  
    System.out.print(v3[i] + " - ");
}
```

---

Un ejemplo completo y funcional lo tienes aquí (al final de la respuesta tengo otro ejemplo más):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pruebas
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Variables enteras auxiliares */
        int n, n2, aux, indice = 0;
        /* Matrices de datos */
        int[] v, v2, v3;
        //Zona codigo 
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese tamaño del arreglo A");
        n = in.nextInt();
        v = new int [n]; //valor asignado
        System.out.println("\nIngrese tamaño del arreglo B");
        n2 = in.nextInt();
        v2 = new int [n2]; //valor asignado
        /* Genero la matriz final con la suma de elementos */
        v3 = new int[n + n2];

        //Lleno arreglo A
        System.out.println("\nArreglo A: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            v[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1);
            /* Agregamos a la matriz final el elemento */
            v3[indice++] = v[i];
            System.out.print(v[i] + " - "); //arreglo original}
        } 
        System.out.println("\nEl arreglo A, ordenado, es5: ");          
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                          
            for( int j = i ; j < n ; j++){                          
                if ( v[j]< v[i] ) {                             
                    aux = v[j];                                     
                    v[j]= v[i];                                     
                    v[i]= aux;
                } 
            } System.out.print(v[i] + " - "); 
        }
        //Lleno arreglo B
        System.out.println("\nArreglo B: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            v2[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1); 
            /* Agregamos a la matriz final el elemento */
            v3[indice++] = v2[i];
            System.out.print(v2[i] + " - "); //arreglo original}

        } 
        System.out.println("\nEl arreglo B, ordenado, es: ");          
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {                          
            for( int j = i ; j < n2 ; j++){                          
                if ( v2[j]< v2[i] ) {                             
                    aux = v2[j];                                     
                    v2[j]= v2[i];                                     
                    v2[i]= aux;
                } 
            }  
            System.out.print(v2[i] + " - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\nEl arreglo completo, ordenado, es: ");          
        for (int i = 0; i < v3.length; i++) {                          
            for( int j = i ; j < v3.length ; j++){                          
                if ( v3[j]< v3[i] ) {                             
                    aux = v3[j];                                     
                    v3[j]= v3[i];                                     
                    v3[i]= aux;
                } 
            }  
            System.out.print(v3[i] + " - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

---

Otro ejemplo algo más limpio y haciendo uso de [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pruebas
{
    static void listar(String encabezado, int[] elementos) {
        System.out.println(encabezado);
        if (elementos.length == 0) return;
        System.out.print(elementos[0]);
        for (int n = 1; n < elementos.length; n++) System.out.print(", " + elementos[n]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1, n2, i3 = 0;
        //Zona codigo 
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese tamaño del arreglo A");
        n1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nIngrese tamaño del arreglo B");
        n2 = in.nextInt();

        /* Matrices de datos */
        int[] v1 = new int[n1], v2 = new int[n2], v3 = new int[n1 + n2];

        //Lleno arreglo A
        System.out.println("\nArreglo A: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            v1[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1);
            /* Agregamos a la matriz final el elemento */
            v3[i3++] = v1[i];
        }
        listar("Listado A sin ordenar", v1);
        Arrays.sort(v1);
        listar("Listado A ordenado", v1);

        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            v2[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*50+1); 
            /* Agregamos a la matriz final el elemento */
            v3[i3++] = v2[i];
        } 
        listar("Listado B sin ordenar", v2);
        Arrays.sort(v2);
        listar("Listado B ordenado", v2);

        listar("Listado COMPLETO sin ordenar", v3);
        Arrays.sort(v3);
        listar("Listado COMPLETO ordenado", v3);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo estas dos matrices:

```
int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int a2[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
```

Creamos una nueva matriz cuyo tamaño sea la suma de las dos anteriores:

```
int a[] = new int[a1.length+a2.length];
```

Copiamos el primer array (los parámetros de la función son: array de entrada, índice por donde empieza, array donde se copiará, índice donde empieza la copia, y número de elementos a guardar):

```
System.arraycopy(a1, 0, a, 0, a1.length);
```

El segundo array lo copiaremos de la misma manera, solo que comenzaremos por el elemento siguiente al que llegamos en la copia del primer array:

```
System.arraycopy(a2, 0, a, a1.length, a2.length);
```

Por último, decir que un array puede ordenarse fácilmente utilizando la función `sort()`. Te dejo un enlace donde podrás consultar los parámetros utilizados en el ordenamiento: http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:Arrays.sort()